# Open web analytic: не отправляются данные при открытии сайта

Tags: php, docker

Я собрал docker контейнер с `owa 1.7.8`.
Прописал в файле `/etc/hosts` `192.168.2.100 space2.local`, по этому адресу будет отслеживаемая страница.

В настройках `owa` добавил запись для `space2.local` и в html добавил сгенерированный JS-код.

При открытии страницы видно что скрипт скачивается с сервера `owa` но ничего не происходит.
Я добавил на страницу несколько кнопок, но никакой реакции.
В статистике так же не видно что было посещение страницы.

Мне кажется я всё сделал как было написано в документации, но похоже что-то упускаю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалось что у меня в браузере был включен запрет на отслеживание что и не позволяло работать скрипту.
После отключения всё заработало как надо.